# Show mapping of factor levels and factor values in R

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm wondering if there's any function to show the mapping of levels and values of a factor variable in R? For example I would expect an output like this:

*Fac_level: "yes" - Value: "1"*,

*Fac_level: "no" - Value: "2"*, etc.

That would be very helpful while working with unknown data sets for the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
x <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:10], 20, TRUE))
> x
# [1] I I I H D E I H F D J G D A F F B H I F
#Levels: A B D E F G H I J

data.frame(levels = unique(x), value = as.numeric(unique(x)))
#  levels value
#1      I     8
#2      H     7
#3      D     3
#4      E     4
#5      F     5
#6      J     9
#7      G     6
#8      A     1
#9      B     2
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers - this one is what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 2):

`levels(df$column)` should tell you their order, they are numbered sequentially based on their order, this shows when you do something like `as.numeric` (which is often a mistake)

```
test <- factor(c("yes","no"))
levels(test)
[1] "no"  "yes"
as.numeric(test)
[1] 2 1
```